# Export images from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, export

I'm building a huge inventory and sales management program on top of Dynamics CRM 2011. I've got a lot done but I'm kinda stuck on one part:

Images are stored in the database encoded as base64 with a MimeType column. I'm wondering how I might extract those images programmatically on a schedule to be sent as part of a data transfer to synchronize another DB.

I have a SQL Server Agent job that exports a view I created. I'm thinking about writing a program that will take that resultant CSV and use it to get a list of products we need to pull images for, and then it queries the DB and saves the files as say productserial-picnum.ext

Is that the best way to do that? Is there an easier way to pull the images out of the DB and into files?

I'm hoping it will be able to only export images that have changed since say a Last Modified column or something.

I don't know C# at all, VB, PHP and JavaScript enough to do some damage though..

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to achieve this in TSQL itself

```
OPEN cursor with qualifying records (where now>lastmodified etc)

For Each Record
Select Binary Data into "@BinaryData
Convert "@BinaryData to @VarcharData (Something like below will work)
    SET @VarcharData = CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@BinaryData")))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')

Write @VarcharData to file (on server or a network drive if the agent is configured to write out)
Close File
Next Record
```

Comment: wow, this looks like it'd do what I need except that I'm guessing this is pseudocode and I don't know how to interpret it. I'm sorry, very new to TSQL (I know.. less than a little about MySQL). Are there some resources you'd recommend me look at so I can understand this better? Thank you for your help!